# Parse and Modify the HTML file using Java

Tags: java, html-parser

I have to parse a given HTML and modify its content and save the modified version.

My HTML Input:

```
<div>
<div class="post-text"><p>@MarcoS had an excellent solution using a NodeTraversor to make a list of nodes to change at <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/6594828/1861357">https://stackoverflow.com/a/6594828/1861357</a> and I only very slightly modified his method which replaces a node (a set of tags) with the data in the node plus whatever information you would like to add.</p>

<p>To store a String in memory I used a static <code>StringBuilder</code> to save the HTML in memory. </p>

<p>First we read in the HTML file (that is manually specified, this can be changed), then we make a series of checks to change whatever nodes with any data that we want.</p>

<p>The one problem that I didn't fix in the solution by MarcoS was that it split each individual word, instead of looking at a line. However I just used '-' for multiple words, because otherwise it places the string directly after that word.</p>

<p>So a full implementation: </p>
</div>
<div>
<div class="post-text" itemprop="description">

        <p>Recently I was recommended to use JSoup to parse and modify HTML documents. </p>

<p>However what if I have a HTML document that I want to modify (to send, store somewhere else, etc.), how might I go about doing that without changing the original document? </p>
</div>
```

My problem is I have to find "@MarcoS had an excellent solution using a NodeTraversor to make a list of nodes to change at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6594828/1861357 and I only" in the html and put a `div tag` (or whatever) around it (Not around it's parent tag or whole paragraph).
The text I search for will have html tags in between.

I want the output like this:

```
 <div class="post-text"><p><div id="myDiv">@MarcoS had an excellent solution using a NodeTraversor to make a list of nodes to change at <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/6594828/1861357">https://stackoverflow.com/a/6594828/1861357</a> and I only</div>......</div>
```

Is RegEx the only solution or can any HTML Parser can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use regexp if you don't want to use some XML parser:

```
String xmlStr = "some_xml";
xmlStr = xml.replaceAll(">\\s+<", "><").trim();
```